# how to divide the handling of gzip/brotli compression between nodeJs and nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, nginx, gzip, reverse-proxy, brotli

i have setup nginx as a reverse proxy for my nodejs app, now i have some static files which are pre-compressed to brotli and gzip and are returned upon request.

```
app.use(
  expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
    enableBrotli: true
  }) 
);
```

my nginx config:

```
upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
        keepalive 64;
    }
    
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        
        server_name www.my-website.com;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/main.key;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/main.crt;
       
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            
            proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        }
    }
```

now my problem is nginx either overrides them and returns it's own on the fly gzip compression or sometimes it reaturn the response from nodejs and does not compress the dynamic responses either!

this drastically different behaviour for no apparent reason really has got me confused.

how can i have nginx accept returned responses from "expressStaticGzip" as is and perform gzip compression on dynamic responses?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Compressing between nginx and your node app makes no sense. Let nginx handle the compression. BTW: Serving static files should also do nginx instead of node.

Comment: @Marc there are 2 problems with that... first i want to use brotli compression as well and second nginx won't return the precompressed files which are already available even when "gzip_static on" is set and performs the on the fly compression.

Comment: @Marc i thought about Serving static files with nginx too but couldn't figure out a way to config nginx in a way that serves the static files for get requests itself and proxies other requests to nodejs. i tried using "alias" but got an error.

Comment: For the later one: Set a root folder and use: `try_files $uri $uri/ @my_nodejs_upstream` For your first problem, just set the correct parameter to tell nginx to compress the files how you like them. Brotli module for nginx: https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli

Comment: @Marc oh ty worked like a charm! just one question, could using try_files potentially gives us a major performance penalty?

Comment: Nothing that i ever noticed. NGINX is in fact a high performance webserver. I doubt that you ever reach that point where you notice some bad impact